# Pandas plot bar order categories

Tags: python, pandas, plot, categories

I have a dataset with a categorical variable that contains three unique values, "low", "medium" and "high":

```
df.CatVar.value_counts()
Out[93]: 
Medium    35832
Low       25311
High      12527
Name: CatVar, dtype: int64
```

I am trying to plot the number of unique values as a bar-plot. However, the following code gives me the bars in the order ["Medium", "Low", "High"]

```
df.CatVar.value_counts().plot(kind="bar")
```

How do I change the order of the bars in the plot?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are 2 possible solutions - change order of `index` before plot - by [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) or `loc`:

```
df.CatVar.value_counts().reindex(["Low", "Medium", "High"]).plot(kind="bar")
```

```
df.CatVar.value_counts().loc[["Low", "Medium", "High"]].plot(kind="bar")
```

Or use [`ordered categorical`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html), so after `value_counts` get order by `categories` parameter:

```
df.CatVar = pd.Categorical(df.CatVar, categories=["Low", "Medium", "High"], ordered=True)
df.CatVar.value_counts(sort=False).plot(kind="bar")
```

---

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'CatVar':['Low','Medium','Low','Low','Medium','High']})
print (df)
   CatVar
0     Low
1  Medium
2     Low
3     Low
4  Medium
5    High

df.CatVar.value_counts().reindex(["Low", "Medium", "High"]).plot(kind="bar")
```

[image: pic]

Comment: I feel like your first approach is kind of what I also did. But as your solution is more detailed, and your second suggestion is a better solution for the specific problem, you have earned my "accept this answer" ;)

Comment: @ViggoTW - Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

The following code solved my problem:

```
df.CatVar.value_counts()[['Low', 'Medium', 'High']].plot(kind="bar")
```

Answer (score 4):

If you do not mind using `seaborn`, you can use [countplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html) and it has parameter to pass the `order`:

```
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'CatVar':['Low','High','Low','Low','Medium']})
sns.countplot(x='CatVar', data=df, order=['Low', 'Medium', 'High']);
```

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to solve this while introducing the fewest amount of new libraries. However, your solution will is nice to have here for people who already use Seaborn and are struggling with similar problems :) (+1)